# Updating main.scss file if one of the imports is changed

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have the following SASS structure:
**app/css/main.scss** (compiled to main.css)
   **/components/_.scss** (imported to main.scss)

The only file that I am watching at the moment is **main.scss**. Once I change that file, it checks all the imports and refreshes the css with the from all the **_component.scss**.

What I'd like to accomplish is to watch for changes on the **_component.scss** files and refresh **main.scss** if a change has been made on any of the _component.scss files. At the moment, I could't find a way to setup a watcher(GULP) to update **main.scss** if one of the imported **_component.scss** files is changed.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Gulp you can watch the entire folder where you store .scss files.

Let's suppose every .scss files are contained in a **scss** folder.
There you'll have your main.scss (the file that will be converted in main.css) and all your partial files (whose name starts with **_**. For example your _component.scss).

Let's suppose you have a destination folder called **stylesheets** for the compiled css file too.

Then you can use the following Gulp script to manage the watching process:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./stylesheets'))
});



gulp.task('watch', function() {
    return gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
    .on('change', function(event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path.slice(event.path.indexOf('/scss/'),event.path.length) + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });
});
```

Now run the task watch with the command **gulp watch**.

To learn more about Gulp-sass follow this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Comment: Thank you. Additional to your comment, I'd add that if your _scss files are in the component folder, you need to follow from the very root of the directory and for every change to recompile the css. Otherwise nothing indicates to the main.scss that the imports were changed.

Answer (score 0):

watch all scss files, just use file mask(example: *.scss, **/*.scss)

Comment: A bit clarification - files in scss starting with underscore are ignored and not compiled to css. So that is solved, but then the main.scss file cant detect any changed made on the imported .scss files.